# Gitlab CICD - denied when I push image into container registry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab.com ci/cd to push images into gitlab registry. I had 2 repositories already and pushing images into registries as **registry.gitlab.com/group1/project1** and **registry.gitlab.com/group1/project2**.

Now I have another 2 repos up and running. I want to run CI/CD for the new projects. I also want to push images into different registries and names them as follows : **registry.gitlab.com/group2/project1** and **registry.gitlab.com/group2/project2**
And I am getting following error:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Does free gitlab provide only 2 registries? Do I need to pay to create more registries ?

Answer (score 4):

The example `.gitlab-ci.yml` below is to lint, build, test, and tag container images for your GitLab project into the matching image registry. Before you can interact with your image registry, you need to login, see the `docker login` lines, and the GitLab CI Runner uses a generated token for this, but only matches the current project. And also only when you have enabled the `Container Registry` in the *Setting -> General* section

```yaml
---
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - verify
  - build
  - test
  - release

variables:
  CI_DOCKER_IMAGE:  ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  CI_DOCKER_TAG:    ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
  CI_DOCKER_BRANCH: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
  CI_DOCKER_LATEST: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest

Docker lint:
  stage: verify
  image: projectatomic/dockerfile-lint
  script:
    - dockerfile_lint -p -f Dockerfile

Docker build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE} .
    - docker push ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE}

Docker test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - docker pull ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE}
    - docker run ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE} /path/to/test.sh

Release branch:
  stage: release
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - docker pull ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE}
    - docker tag ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE} ${CI_DOCKER_BRANCH}
    - docker push ${CI_DOCKER_BRANCH}
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master

Release tag:
  stage: release
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - docker pull ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE}
    - docker tag ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE} ${CI_DOCKER_TAG}
    - docker push ${CI_DOCKER_TAG}
  only:
    - tags

Release latest:
   stage: release
   before_script:
     - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}
   script:
     - docker pull ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE}
     - docker tag ${CI_DOCKER_IMAGE} ${CI_DOCKER_LATEST}
     - docker push ${CI_DOCKER_LATEST}
   only:
     - master
```

If you want to push to an image registry other than the default registry that comes with your project, then you should provide the credentials to the *CI/CD -> Variables* section. Also, `.gitlab-ci.yml` should be modified to have the correct **registry**, **username** and **accesstoken** variables in the YAML file.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can tag docker images as old project and then able to push. I event tried steps manually from my local and it still doing same. If I tag them as previous project For Ex: registry.gitlab.com/group1/project1 or registry.gitlab.com/group1/project2 then I am able to push images. But if I tag them as registry.gitlab.com/group2/project1 or registry.gitlab.com/group2/project2 then it is giving denied error. I think in gitlab free version we can only create 2 registries max. I need to confirm that

Comment: @nani21984 I have multiple registries with the free version without an issue, then again mine is an early adopter account so it may have been grandfathered into something. Keep in mind that group1 and group2 are two separate entities. Also when it is a personal account and organizational group. If you can give your question more details with examples, then we might see where things go wrong.